# "Membership can not be used as a Result Column for profile searches" - why not?

Tags: civimember, profile, search, user, ui

What can be done to make Membership - Membership Status in particular - a Result Column for profile searches? I want to be able to show Status in a Search View.

Comment: Joe - what does the outcome need to be here - who is it for? is it something Views does more easily perhaps?

Comment: Peter, one goal is to be able to have a Search View which shows the members of a Group and the Membership Status(es) for each member of that Group, with other fields - for example, in the Leadership Ladder profile/search view in our Citizen Action production site. I'll try doing it in Views but having the ability to easily add Membership Status as a Results Column directly in Civi - whether in a Search View or a Report - whether one is on Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla - seems pretty basic and essential for a CRM.

Comment: Can't you go to Advanced Search & select the memberships you want - you can select which statuses you want, too - the results show status and date of membership if you select to show results as Membership - unless I don't understand your question

Comment: Joe - if someone has multiple memberships (eg old ones and current ones) do you want a single row per contact, or will you accept multiple rows? The thing with memberships to contacts is that it is not a 1-1 relationship. Is the 'Search View' meant to be for Contacts or for Memberships?

Comment: Pete- I would like to see all membership statuses for any contact in any Group via Profiles/ Search Views in Civi - or at least the latest/last membership status - and if that contact has never had a membership, for the contact name to still appear, especially, because we need to sign them up as a member.

Comment: Lesley - here's why Search Builder and Advanced Search don't (yet) work for this. Say I have group of contacts, and I select that Group in Search Builder ( Group(s) = group_name ) and select Membership Status(s) Not Empty. I get a result of  just those group member names who have a membership status - but not result showing status - so I have to click through each record individually to see the membership status. This also will not show any members of the Group with no status - because they are not members.

Comment: Lesley - this is part 2 of the above comment. Using Advanced Search, I can choose the same group, and Membership Status of Current, Expired or Terminated and I get the same thing - a list of names only, and again I have to click through each individual record, and again, members of that Group who have never been members do not appear in the result anyway. So - a Profile/Search View that would show all, or at least latest, Membership Status would be very useful.

Comment: Lesley - this is part 3 of the above comment. And for the fields selected through Search Builder or Advanced Search to show in the result list - rather than just the contact name - would be very useful.

Comment: Lesley - my apologies for not reading your answer more carefully. Selecting Display Results as Memberships does show the selected Membership(s) for each contact in that Group (I chose only Current and Expired). So if I could select Display Results as Contacts (using my custom Search View) *and* any associated membership(s) for that contact (if any exist), that would be ideal.

Comment: Joe - still sounds like a View might be simplest

Comment: Petednz, yeah working on a view.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you go to Advanced Search & select the memberships you want - you can select which statuses you want, too - the results show status and date of membership if you select to **Display Results As** Membership - unless I don't understand your question.

Note: For v4.5 and below, **Display Results As** is in the top right of the Basic Criteria frame in an Advanced Search.

In 4.6 **Display Results As** is in the "Search Settings" grouping at the bottom of the Basic Criteria frame in an Advanced Search.

Comment: Lesley - my apologies for not reading your answer more carefully. Selecting Display Results as Memberships does show the selected Membership(s) for each contact in that Group (I chose only Current and Expired). So if I could select Display Results as Contacts (using my custom Search View), showing *all* contacts in that Group, members and non-members, and any associated membership(s) for that contact (if any exist), that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to finding people who have aren't members, if you can't do this via a view I think you will need a smart group of people in your Group who have a membership and then use the include/exclude custom search (or perhaps Search Builder) to find people in the Group but not in the smart group.

Answer (score 1):

Joe - I think a View is probably a good approach for you to take. If you do so, pls consider attaching it here so others can try it out.

Comment: Peter, thx, will do that